# scroll text if textsize is greater in android

Tags: android

Hello
In my android application i am using a table inside which am using a text view to display the content.
The issue is like i would like to scroll the text automatically like in marquee if the text content is greator than screen size.

Is there any way that i can achieve this in android.

Please share your valuable suggestions.

Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 1):

I believe adding `android:ellipsize="marquee"` to the TextView should do the trick.